# word count(frequency) spark rdd scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, word-count

if I have an rdd accross cluster and I want to do the word count

not only count the appear times,
I want to get the frequency, which is defined as count/total count

What is the best and efficient way to do so in scala?
How can I do reduction job and calculate total number at the same time within one workflow?

BTW I know purely word count can be done in this way.

```
text_file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

but what is the difference if I use aggregate? in terms of spark job workflow

```
    val result = pairs
       .aggregate(Map[String, Int]())((acc, pair) => 
            if(acc.contains(pair._1)) 
                acc ++ Map[String, Int]((pair._1, acc(pair._1)+1)) 
            else 
                acc ++ Map[String, Int]((pair._1, pair._2))
          , 
          (a, b) => 
              (a.toSeq ++ b.toSeq)
                 .groupBy(_._1)
                 .mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _))
       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
val total = counts.map(x => x._2).sum() 
val freq  = counts.map(x => (x._1, x._2/total))
```

There exists also the concept of *Accumulator* which is a write-only variable and you could use it to avoid using the `sum()` action, but your code would need a lot of change.